# How do I fix TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, random, pydev

I am creating a 2D RPG game and want the Defence stat from a base number to increase by the random numbers between 4 and 8 as the player's level increases by 1 each time.

In the previous while loop the int() works fine but this one does not and I can't remember how it got fixed.

I have a class Player which I have def Shield(self): then I have if statements of small shield, medium shield, large shield. Each shield depends on what the player class is, such as; Assassin or Warrior which are if statements within the shield if statements. within the player classes if statements I have self.S_Defence += # and as you can see up there self.D_Stats = self.S_Defence, but the code up there should be updating and resetting the number to an increased number

```
        self.S_Exp = 600
        while self.S_Exp >= 0 + (self.S_Level * 100):
            self.S_Level += 1
            self.S_Exp -= ((self.S_Level - 1) * 250)
            self.S_Level_Stats = [self.S_Exp, self.S_Level]

            self.Increased_Defence = []
            for loop in self.D_Stats:
                loop += random.randint(4, 8)
                self.Increased_Defence.append(loop)
                self.D_Stats = self.Increased_Defence
                self.D_Stats = [self.S_Defence]
```

What is expected is if the player level increases, the specific stat in this case Defence should increase by 4,5,6,7, or 8

Comment: What is `self.D_Stats` before the `for` loop ?

Comment: I have a class Player which I have def Shield(self): then I have if statements of small shield, medium shield, large shield. Each shield depends on what the player class is, such as; Assassin or Warrior which are if statements within the shield if statements. within the player classes if statements I have self.S_Defence += # and as you can see up there self.D_Stats = self.S_Defence, but the code up there should be updating and resetting the number to an increased number

Comment: Can you please explain what is the expected result of the last two lines in the `for()` loop.

Comment: The second last line is to update self.D_Stats to update, equalling the pervious number + random.randint(4,8). for example the base stat (30) + the random number (4) now equalling 34. The last line is just restating that self.D_Stats(defence stats)  is equalled to self.S_Defence (Shield defence)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `_Stats` list/arrays ?  For example, the code duplicates Player member variables into one of these lists: `self.P_Level_Stats = [self.P_Exp, self.P_Level]`.  Why not just use the `self.P_Exp` and `self.P_Level` ?

Comment: In the first while loop if there is a certain amount of exp it levels up the player, then takes away however much exp was needed for the level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The definition for `self.D_Stats` is not a list, see the definition for 
`self.P_Stats = [self.P_HP, self.P_Attack, self.P_Speed]`.  This isn't working "the same" because (I guess) it should be: `self.D_Stats = [self.S_Defence]`

Python `for` loops need to take an [*iterable*](https://pythonbasics.org/iterable/).  So in this `for` loop, `self.D_Stats` must be a list, or suchlike.

```
for loop in self.D_Stats:
    loop += random.randint(4, 8)
    self.Increased_Defence.append(loop)
    self.D_Stats = self.Increased_Defence
    self.D_Stats = self.S_Defence
```

If `self.D_Stats` is an integer, then use the python [`range()` function](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-range-function), which creates an iterable from `0 -> <argument>-1`, or otherwise with extra arguments.

```
for loop in range( self.D_Stats ):
    loop += random.randint(4, 8)
```

The body of the `for` loop looks a bit strange too.  `self.D_Stats` is set twice, so the `self.Increased_Defence` value is being lost.  Is `self.D_Stats` supposed to be a list/array and be `.append()`ed to ?

Based on the description of what the code should do, I think it needs to look something like this, as the "Shield Defence" doesn't seem to have any relation to the base defence stat increasing.  We're increasing levels, and "using up" experience points.  So the `while()` loop iterates, decrementing experience points, but increasing `D_Stats`.  This is how I understand it from the description anyway.

```
while self.S_Exp >= 0 + (self.S_Level * 100):
    self.S_Level += 1
    self.S_Exp -= ((self.S_Level - 1) * 250)
    self.S_Level_Stats = [self.S_Exp, self.S_Level]

    points_increase = random.randint(4, 8)
    self.Increased_Defence.append(points_increase)
    self.D_Stats += points_increase
```

EDIT2:  Looking at your code, I think it would be neater, cleaner and *shorter* if you use data structures to hold some of the stat values.  The Weapon modifier can be greatly simplified:

```
def Weapon(self, Weapon):
    weapon_mods = { "Dagger":[6,0], "Knife":[5,0], "Sword":[7,0], "Axe":[7,-5] } #etc
    if ( Weapon in weapon_mods ):
        attack_mod, speed_mod = weapon_mods[ Weapon ]
        self.P_Attack += attack_mod
        self.P_Speed  += speed_mod
        self.P_Stats = [self.P_HP, self.P_Attack, self.P_Speed]
```

I think it's better to always *add* the modifier, and use negative/positive modifiers. It makes the logic simpler (and what if you want to make a weapon that increases attack speed?)

Comment: I'm not sure, the previous code for a different while loop is slightly the same but has more objects within self.P_Stats, self.P_Stats = [self.P_HP, self.P_Attack, self.P_Speed] but both loops are the same except for P_Stats and D_Stats

Comment: Maybe you could add the player class definition to the question.

Comment: If it's not too big, it would help.

Comment: A couple hundred lines

Comment: I was gonna do the same for the player attack but wanted to figure out the defence first

Comment: Ok I'll try it but that doesn't change the initial problem

Comment: I appreciate the tips and will retry, going through step by step from your edits. I will look through my code again and see if I can fix it. Thank you for your time

Comment: I re read your response and now realise what you mean by it not being in a list and may have an idea on how to fix it